# How to add inside legend for a combined plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following df and ggplot2 code to make a scatter plot but failed to add a legend inside the plot. Thanks :)

```
x1 = 1:5 
x2 = 6:10
y1 = 3:7
y2 = 2:6

df <- data.frame(x1, y1, x2, y2)

ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x1, y = y1),col='red') + geom_point(aes(x = x2, y = y2),col='black')
```

Comment: place the col arguments inside the aes definition

Comment: You can then use `scale_color_manual` to change the label names

Comment: Thanks Patrik_P it worked but then I doesn't let me to change the colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
x1 = 1:5 
x2 = 6:10
y1 = 3:7
y2 = 2:6

df <- data.frame(x1, y1, x2, y2)

ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x1, y = y1, col = "1")) + 
geom_point(aes(x = x2, y = y2, col = "2")) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "black"))
```

In the above code, by putting col = "1" and col = "2" **inside** the aesthetics aes(), you're telling ggplot to add a colour dimension to the plot (and not just colour the points "red" and "black"). Hence, you see a legend now. Then, by setting colour equal to "1" and "2", you're saying to use these as labels. `scale_colour_manual` allows you to change these colours to red and black, instead of the red and blue" default.

The same applies anytime you want to add any dimension to the plot. But, instead of using `col` and `scale_colour_manual`, you would use an alternative such as `shape` and `scale_shape_manual`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of long format data input

```
#data into long format
x1 = 1:5 
x2 = 6:10
y1 = 3:7
y2 = 2:6
df <- data.frame(x=c(x1, x2), y=c(y1, y2), group=rep(c("x1", "x2"), c(5, 5)))
#plot it
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y = y, colour=group))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "black"))
```